# WPF TabControl Binding issue

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, prism

I have `TabControl` with two tabs: main time and additional time. Main view model contains main hours and additional hours as properties, first tab bound to main hours, second tab - to additional hours. Each hour has a clear command (`DelegateCommand` from `Prism`). On the top of `TabControl` there is a button with command "Clear all" (`CompositeCommand`). Hours are creating in the constructor of main view model.

**Issue:**

Commands from additional hours are not exists cause of and they are not participate in command "Clear all", and button "Clear all" is not enabled until I select second tab (in the first tab is nothing to clear, but on the secons there is).

I tried to disabled virtualizing in `TabControl` but it didn't help me. Also after loading data I call `clearCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged` for each hour.

**Update:**
When I iterate through hours in debugger and watch if command can execute it's all fine and UI updates properly. But without debugger it's not.

Comment: Why is there something to save on the second tab when you still did not select the tab? Don't you have to change something to have something to save? And don't you have to select the tab to change something?

Comment: @PVitt: 1. Yes; 2. Don't; 3. Don't. First tab is empty (has no data), and second tab has data that can be saved. Actually it's save command, but I updated post and rename command to "Clear" for fully understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but there are two things I can think of that might cause unusual behavior in your design

1. Prism's `DelegateCommand` does not automatically re-query `CanExecute` if a parameter changes. To verify if this is your problem or not, I'd switch to using a `RelayCommand` of some kind.... I often use [Galasoft's MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) `RelayCommand` when I want a command to automatically re-evaluate it's `CanExecute` when a parameter changes
2. By default, WPF unloads TabItems that are not visible. So if the `SaveAllButton.Enabled` property is based off of `Tab1.SaveButton.Enabled` and `Tab2.SaveButton.Enabled`, Tab2 has something to save, but Tab1 does not, and Tab1 has focus, then the SaveAll button will be disabled because Tab2 is not visible and therefore, not loaded. To test if this is the case, switch to using something like a `ListBox`. If it is the case, you can use the code found [here](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/eburke/archive/2009/04/30/keeping-the-wpf-tab-control-from-destroying-its-children.aspx) to keep your TabControl from unloading non-visible tabs.

Comment: Userful link, but it didn't help me. After loadind data I call `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` for all hours, so the poblem is not in `DelegateCommand` (I think, but I'll try `RElayCommand` too).

Comment: @JohnKZ Did you try something other than a `TabControl`? Your problem could be that the Tab isn't loaded until it's selected (#2)

Comment: :Thank you Rachel. I removed `TabControl` and do not use `ListBox`. I just changes `Visibility` property for layouts and use `RadioButton`s to change visible layout.